# Text won't line up

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root =Tk()
text = '["apple", "banana", "orange]"'
data = text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace('"', "")
lst = list(data.split(","))

t = Text(root)
for x in lst:
    t.insert(END, x + '\n')
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The output is like this:
[image]

But I want it to be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because after those `replace(...)`, the final result of `data` will be:

```
'apple, banana, orange'
```

So the result of `list(data.split(","))` will be:

```
['apple', ' banana', ' orange']
```

To fix it, use `list(data.split(", "))` instead for your case.

---

However you can use `json` to parse `text`:

```py
from tkinter import *
import json

root =Tk()

#text = '["apple", "banana", "orange]"'  # ]" should be "]
text = '["apple", "banana", "orange"]'
lst = json.loads(text)

t = Text(root)
for x in lst:
    t.insert(END, x + '\n')
t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix with minimal changes by simply using `x.strip()` inside for loop as:

```
t.insert(END, x.strip() + '\n')
```

In longer run you might want to fix your `lst` as:

```
lst = [i.strip() for i in data.split(",")]
```

This way your list does not include trailing or leading spaces and is more useful in longer run and your code as it is works as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying `insert x` then after first element it took additional some space. To remove space use `strip()` with `x`. Follow the code

```
from tkinter import *
root =Tk()
text = '["apple", "banana", "orange]"'
data = text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace('"', "")
lst = list(data.split(","))

t = Text(root)
for x in lst:
    t.insert(END, x.strip() + '\n')
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
from tkinter import *
root =Tk()
text = '["apple", "banana", "orange]"'
data = text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace('"', "")
lst = list(data.split(","))

t = Text(root)
for x in lst:
    t.insert(END, x.strip() + '\n')
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note:

```
x.strip()
```